# Login in MySQL with role

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong with this code?

I want to have a role in my data base but this code wont work :(

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';

$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="" AND $_SESSION['userRole'] = ('admin')) {
    $user_login->redirect('admin.php');
} elseif ($user_login->is_logged_in()!="" AND $_SESSION['userRole'] = ('user')) {
    $user_login->redirect('user.php'); 
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);

    if($user_login->login($email,$upass) AND $_SESSION['userRole'] = ('admin')) {
        $user_login->redirect('admin.php');
    } elseif ($user_login->login($email,$upass) AND $_SESSION['userRole'] = ('user')) {
        $user_login->redirect('user.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?  we want to help you but provide as much information as possible.

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are facing, but I see one error in every of your `IF` condition >> if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="" AND $_SESSION['userRole'] = ('admin'))  -- You are missing `==`  here $_SESSION['userRole'] == ('admin')